# How can lock and hide value of a Cell in google speadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want lock and hide value of some cell in speadsheet:

This is my code using to lock a cell, but it still show value.

Can i hide value (not allow other user view)?

```
function onOpen(e){
        var oSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        for(var i=2;i<10;i++)
              {
                if(oSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() !="")
                {

                  var protection = oSheet.getRange(i, 2).protect().setDescription('protectedrange');
                  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
                  protection.addEditor(me);
                  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
                  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
                    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
                  }
                }
              }
    }
```

Comment: It highly depends on what exactly do you mean by "hide" - could you clarify what would you like to achieve exactly? If you mean hide an individual cell entirely, I don't think so, API supports only row and cloumn hide

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets can hide sheets, columns and rows but not single cells.

If hiding a sheet, column or row doesn't work for you, instead of writing the value to a cell you could use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

Comment: "hide": i only Cell not display value ( the same with set none color and not allow display on top Frame when select cell). Can it?

Comment: It's not possible to use CSS for cell content. Even if you set the font color the same as the cell background, the value is visible on the formula bar.

Comment: Can disable select a cell?